# Scraping youtube with beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

YouTube's HTML has some custom elements such as `yt-formatted-string`, you see you cannot decode that in the `HTML` parser without having youtube's javascript, `beautifulsoup4` is parsing it wrong.

Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4E4yAktjug"

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    data_container = doc.find('div', {'id': 'info-container'})

    print(data_container.prettify())
```

prints this:

```
<div id="info-container">
 <div class="skeleton-light-border-bottom" id="primary-info">
  <div class="text-shell skeleton-bg-color" id="title">
  </div>
  <div id="info">
   <div class="text-shell skeleton-bg-color" id="count">
   </div>
   <div class="flex-1">
   </div>
   <div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-button skeleton-bg-color">
    </div>
    <div class="menu-button skeleton-bg-color">
    </div>
    <div class="menu-button skeleton-bg-color">
    </div>
    <div class="menu-button skeleton-bg-color">
    </div>
    <div class="menu-button skeleton-bg-color">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="skeleton-light-border-bottom" id="secondary-info">
  <div id="top-row">
   <div class="flex-1" id="video-owner">
    <div class="skeleton-bg-color" id="channel-icon">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-1" id="upload-info">
     <div class="text-shell skeleton-bg-color" id="owner-name">
     </div>
     <div class="text-shell skeleton-bg-color" id="published-date">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="skeleton-bg-color" id="subscribe-button">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**[EDIT]**
These are the expected values:

2.4M views 
      
    
    
      
        1 year ago

**[End Of EDIT]**

So, when I try to retrieve the view count it returns as None. is there a possible fix?

I tried doing this one by one, first getting the info container, then another element, and then inside that view count, but it returned `NoneType object has no attribute find.`

I also tried listing all spans and extracting the one with views but that was inefficient, confusing, and failed.

Comment: I can't see the view count in the provided HTML code. Can you doublecheck this is the correct code and maybe specify which value you're trying to get?

Comment: Ok! in 20 mins the question will be fixed

Comment: Probably duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402280/use-beautifulsoup-to-get-a-youtube-video-s-information

Comment: Try the solution of the link above, as @dm2 said, the count is not in the retrived HTML. This is probably because you are not calling the JS which generates the number.

Comment: @Rayaankhan,  since there's javascript involved and the `requests` lib does not support that. That's why you get different HTML content. But you still get all the data inside one of the `script` tags and the data lies inside a deep nested `json` which you'll need to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rayaankhan, since there's `javascript` involved and the requests lib does not support that. That's why you get different `HTML` content. But you still get all the data inside one of the `script` tags and the data lies inside a deep nested `JSON` which you'll need to parse –
Ajeet Verma. As you see in Ajeet's comment, The requests library does not return javascript, so I need to externally get the javascript and render the `HTML` with it.